# Android - running app on a usb-connected device

Tags: android, usb, device

I am using **Android Studio** to run my app, and when I plug in my **Moto G phone with a USB cable**, I get the following choice of devices to run my app on: 
`????????????[null]`. My device is not reacting in any way when I do select this option and run. My OS is **Xubuntu 14.04**. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that USB Debugging is enable
2. Connect your device as camera (PTP)

[image]

This link could help you: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Android_Studio_Apps_on_a_Physical_Android_Device